An import error occurs in UCX version 0.49
I tried to run the assessment job from databricks UCX.

It fails directly with an error :

ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidState' from 'databricks.sdk.errors' (/databricks/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/databricks/sdk/errors/init.py)

I'm running the latest version of UCX, 0.49. The runtime is 16.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12).
Is it a bug in this version ? how can I downgrade ? the 0.48 was working well.

problem is on databricks side. The version will probably be bumped. in the mean time :
databricks labs install ucx@fix/pin-databricks-sdk

